# RTE "Show Editor" edit adds one extra <a> to HTML <a>

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

We wrote below code in RTE "HTML editor". Saved it. published it.

```
<div class="content-center">
    <a href="https://google.com">
        <div class="button">apply</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then opened "Show Editor" and added few text to existing tags. saved and published the item. While opening the "HTML Editor" again, the code has been modified like below.

```
<div class="content-center">
<a href="https://google.com">
</a>
<div class="button">
<a href="https://google.com">apply</a>
</div>*
```

What should we do to overcome this issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the fact that according to **XHTML** standard you can't put `<div>` inside `<a>`.

According to **Html5** standard, block level elements like `<div>` are allowed in `<a>` tags.

But most probably RTE still works based on older standards.

Solution? Maybe replace `<div>` element with `<span class="div">` and use `span.div { display: block; }` styling?

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: adding <span> removes the text completely. Any other solution do you have.

added this--
<div class="content-center">
<a href="https://google.com">
<span class="button">apply</span>
</a>
</div>
resulted --
<div class="content-center">
<a href="https://google.com">
</a></div>